# How to access a property of a resource in xaml

Tags: xaml

In XAML I have resources in an external resource dictionary, something like this:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Foo"
                 Color="#FFFF0000" />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Bar"
                 Color="#FF00FF00" />
```

I can't change this external resource dictionary.

I have a color collection in my XAML, something like this:

```
<MyObject>
    <MyObject.Colors>
        <Color>#FFFF0000</Color>
        <Color>#FF00FF00</Color>
    </MyObject.Colors>
</MyObject>
```

I'd like to somehow use the `Color` of these `Brush` objects from the external resources to put it inside my color collection, something like:

```
<MyObject>
    <MyObject.Colors>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="Foo" Path="Color" />
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="Bar" Path="Color" />
    </MyObject.Colors>
</MyObject>
```

Of course this `<StaticResource ResourceKey="Foo" Path="Color" />` doesn't work, but is there a way to have access to a property of a resource?

Answer (score -1):

I assume that your ResourceDictionary looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary> 
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Foo"
                     Color="#FFFF0000" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Bar"
                     Color="#FF00FF00" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then you can include this resource dictionary in your Application, UserControll or something with another resource dictionary like this:

```
<Application>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:<project where your resource dictionary is>;component/<path to your resource dictionary>"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Bla" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
    <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource Foo}"/>
    <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource Bar}"/>
    <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource Bla}"/>
</Application>
```

You need to define in which project in your solution the resource dictionary is and the path to the file (without the <>).

It is also possible to extend it locally like in my example (SolidColorBrush with the key "Bla").

You can also add multiple sources to reuse defined data in some resource dictionaries.

**Update:**

I missunderstood the question. You have to split up your SolidColorBrush from the used Color like:

```
<ResourceDictionary> 
    <Color x:Key="FooColor">#FFFF0000</Color>
    <Color x:Key="BarColor">#FF00FF00</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Foo"
                     Color="{StaticResource FooColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Bar"
                     Color="{StaticResource BarColor}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then you can get only the color which is also used by the brush.

Comment: The question is, how can I access the property "Color" of a Brush resource, regardless of where the Brush resource is saved. And since in my case the Brush resource is out of my scope I can't just add a Color resource and make the Brush resource use it.

Comment: @Nostromo i added another example. May it helps.

Comment: Thank you, but as I wrote I can't do that, since the external library with the resources inside is not mine to change and it would be a lot of hassle to get others to change it. That's why I asked if it is somehow possible to have access to a property of an existing resource.